# Keep filenames on primefaces fileupload component

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

My page fully works now with the upload component of PrimeFaces, the thing is that some of the users complain because they think that their files were not uploaded since they don't appear anymore on the list. Is there a way to keep that list of files (with the progress bar filled) shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to create another list containing the name of all the files they uploaded and show it instead of trying to keep the old list?

Comment: Just trying to save time. I read the documentation concerning fileupload and I think it's not possible. Thanks I think I will do what you suggest.